Kafka Streams to join with Ktable
I'm working on Kafka streams and I want to do a join with Stream and KTable. Currently, I have following Streams but I want to know if there is any way to reduce the number of streams and achieve all of the following.
Stream 1 where I'm reading data from source DB.
CREATE STREAM strm_source
  WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='DB_Data',VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');

Stream 2 where I'm extracting the required data
CREATE STREAM strm_transform
  WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='DB_Data_Transform',KEY_FORMAT = 'AVRO', VALUE_FORMAT = 'AVRO') AS SELECT
  TS_MS `eventTimestamp`,
  AFTER->ID `eventKey`,
  AS_VALUE(AFTER->ID) `id`,
  FORMAT_TIMESTAMP(FROM_UNIXTIME(AFTER->UTCDATETIME), 'yyyy-MM-dd') `date`,
  AFTER->ITEMQUANTITY `quantity`
FROM strm_source
PARTITION BY AFTER->ID;

Stream 3 with a primary key to join with the ktable
CREATE STREAM strm_keyed
      (id VARCHAR KEY, date VARCHAR, quantity VARCHAR)
      WITH (kafka_topic='DB_Data_Transform', KEY_FORMAT = 'AVRO', value_format='avro');

Stream 4 for to do a join with the ktable
CREATE STREAM strm_filtered
       WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='DB_Data_Filtered',KEY_FORMAT = 'AVRO',VALUE_FORMAT = 'AVRO')
       AS SELECT
       strm_keyed.id,
       AS_VALUE(strm_keyed.id) AS `id`,
       date AS `date`
       quantity AS `quantity`
       FROM strm_keyed
       INNER JOIN KTBL_DATA ON STRM_KEYED.id = KTBL_DATA.id
       WHERE KTBL_DATA.id IS NOT NULL;

